# Möbius Transformation interchanging two preassigned points in the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Is there a Möbius transformation mapping the upper half plane onto itself that interchange two preassigned points in the upper half plane? If so , how many such Möbius transformations are there?

Here are steps that I followed:

1.we know we can transform upper half plane onto unit circle.

2. I want  to find a Möbius transformation that maps unit circle to unit circle but interchanging the preassigned points.

3.
Finally , if I find a transformation that maps the unit circle to the upper half plane.Then I think we are done.

I have problem in finding the Möbius transformation that maps unit circle to unit circle with interchanging property that already mention.

Does someone have any idea about this?

Comment: the transformations that take the upper half plane to itself are easier to describe, and work with, than what you suggest

Comment: [Question with a related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686074)

Comment: What I think , we need three transformation to do this. But , I am having problem to see how to interchange the points

Comment: You know that you can move the problem to the unit disk. I think that can indeed simplify matters somewhat. Can you show that there exists an automorphism of the unit disk that interchanges $0$ and any preassigned point $a$ in the unit disk? Can you then show that there is an automorphism of the unit disk interchanging two arbitrary preassigned $a,b$ in the unit disk?

Comment: It makes sense. This is what I was trying to do but I have the problem to show there is an automorphism of the unit disk interchanging two arbitrary preassigned points.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Can you find a Möbius transformation interchanging $0$ and $a$?

Comment: I do not have any idea about automorphism that interchanges 0 and a.

Comment: I am still struggling in this problem. I see the sketch of the answer but could not visualize the whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

A Möbius transformation that maps the upper half plane to itself must map the boundary, i.e. the real line, to itself as well.  With the standard definition for the transformation, 
$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d},$$
it is fairly straightforward to see that the parameters $a, b, c, d$ must be real to map the real line to itself (try plugging in $z=0$, $z=\infty$, and then one other real number).

Then since $f$ is supposed to interchange $z_1$ and $z_2$, that means applying $f$ twice should send $z_1$ back to itself, and the same for $z_2$.  Note that $f(f(z))$ is again another Möbius transformation with real coefficients.  You can now solve the equation for the fixed points of the transformation ([or look up the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Fixed_points)).  This should answer the question about whether the transformation is possible.

Comment: I did not get how applying f twice takes the points  back to itself and how does this interchanges the points?

Comment: Note that $f^2$ will have two fixed points in the upper half plane, and has real coefficients, so $f^2$ is simply the identity map.

Answer (score 0):

**Uniqueness of the Transformation**

Some understanding of group actions can help us show that such a transformation (using real coefficients) must be unique (assume $w\ne z$). If $f$ and $g$ are two such transformations, then $f^{-1}\circ g$ is a transformation that fixes both $z$ and $w$. But writing out the equation for $z$ to be a fixed point of $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ reveals (again, for real values $a,b,c,d$) there can only be one fixed point $z$ in the upper half-plane, unless it is the identity. But if it is the identity, $f^{-1}\circ g=\mathrm{id}$ implies $f=g$ are the same transformation.

**Geometry of the Transformation**

The upper half-plane is a model for hyperbolic geometry, which has a metric. The geodesics are semicircles with diameters on the real axis. Around every point there is a group of "hyperbolic rotations" which fix it and whose derivative there rotates tangent vectors. In particular, around $i$, it is $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ (however the kernel of its action is $\{\pm I_2\}$ so maybe we want to think of it as $\mathrm{PSO}(2)$). Given two points $z$ and $w$  we may construct the unique semicircle arc between them. On that arc is a "hyperbolic midpoint" which is the same hyperbolic distance from both $z$ and $w$ (I expect this is not the midpoint according to Euclidean arclength, though). We can swap $z$ and $w$ by applying a $180^{\circ}$ hyperbolic rotation around this midpoint. (Note that if the midpoint was e.g. $i$, we'd need a $90^{\circ}$ rotation matrix in $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ to achieve this effect.)

**Formula for the Transformation**

The equations that say $f$ swaps $w$ and $z$ are given by

$$ \frac{aw+b}{cw+d}=z, \qquad \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=w. $$

Clearing denominators yields

$$ \begin{cases}
aw+b = c(wz)+dz \\
az\,+\,b = c(zw)+dw
\end{cases} $$

Subtracting gives $a(w-z)=d(z-w)$ which implies $d=-a$, and the equation becomes

$$ a(w+z)+b=c(wz). \tag{$\ast$} $$

Taking imaginary parts yields $a\mathrm{Im}(w+z)=c\,\mathrm{Im}(wz)$. This allows us to solve:

$$ \begin{cases}
 a = \lambda \mathrm{Im}(wz) \\
 c = \lambda \mathrm{Im}(w+z)
\end{cases} $$

where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}$. We may solve for $b$ by taking real parts of $(\ast)$ to finally get

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
= \lambda
\begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{Im}(wz) & \mathrm{Re}(wz)\mathrm{Im}(w+z)-\mathrm{Im}(wz)\mathrm{Re}(w+z) \\
\mathrm{Im}(w+z) & -\mathrm{Im}(wz) \end{pmatrix} $$

**Special Example**

Taking $z=w=i$ gives a $90^{\circ}$ rotation matrix, yielding a $180^{\circ}$ hyperbolic rotation around $i$. This is the limiting case of $z,w\to i$ with midpoint $\to i$.